# Flutter TextField onChanged is not worked

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

```
TextField(
                  controller: nicknameController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    textFieldState.isNotEmptyText(value);
                  },
                  onTap: () => textFieldState.onClick(),
                  onTapOutside: (event) {
                    textFieldState.onClick();
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: MaeumGaGymColor.blue500),
                    ),
                    label: PtdTextWidget.regular(
                        '닉네임', 20, MaeumGaGymColor.gray400),
                  ),
                ),
```

```
void isNotEmptyText(String text) {
    if (text == '') {
      _isText = false;
    } else {
      _isText = true;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdol.png)

I tried using this code and pressing the simulator keyboard, but nothing comes up in textField.

I've tried many ways, but I couldn't find any errors like mine.

If anyone knows about this situation, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

to udpate value in widget, you need to rebuild it widget. In your case you have to use `Consumer` widget. ( I assume you are using provider)

```
Consumer<yourStateClass> (
 builder: (context, state, child) {
  return TextField(
      onChange: (value){
        state.isNotEmptyText(value);
     }
   )
 }
)
```

---

but there are more elegant solution. `Textfield` has its own state handler. just use the controller

```
TextField(
  controller: nicknameController,
   onChanged: (value) {
       textFieldState.isNotEmptyText(value); // this update your state value
       nicknameController.text = value; // this is to update textfield state
   },
```

now since the textfield has update its value by the controller, no need to update `notifylistener`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But that doesn't work either

Comment: practically its should be works.  I only can help based on what you provide in your question.